# percentage of two number with enter key works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that consists of `<tr>` and `<td>`'s and I show the percentage of the sold tickets in the third `<td>`. My code works correctly until I have an enter after `<br/>` tag in each `<td>`. For instance, if you press an enter key after each `<br/>` tag my code works correctly otherwise it does not work and does not calculate the percentage of two number. how can I define to my code that does not consider the enter and space between each `<td>`?
here is my snippet :

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(2)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);

  $('span.result', $this).each(function(index, element) {
    let v = $('td:nth-child(1)', $this).text().trim().split(/\r?\n/);
    if (v[index] != null && v[index].trim() == "Mytext") {
      v[index] = td2Value[index];
    }
    if (v[index] != null) {
      $(element).html(Math.round((td2Value[index] * 100 / v[index]) || 0) + '%');
    }

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> avalable</th>
      <th> sold</th>
      <th> result </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        10<br/>Mytext<br>
      </td>
      <td>
        5<br/> 2
        <br/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="result"></span><br/>
        <span class="result"></span><br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `regex`.

```
let v = $('td:nth-child(1)', $this).text().trim().split(/\r?\n/);
```

This line only returns the values, but concatenated.

What you want is a very basic regex `(\d+)` this will match `only` digits(All you need is to separate integers and text in a string).

Use this:

```
 let v = $('td:nth-child(1)', $this).text().trim().split(/(\d+)/).filter(v => v);
```

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(2)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);
  $('span.result', $this).each(function (index, element) {

    let v = $('td:nth-child(1)', $this).text().trim().split(/(\d+)/).filter(v => v);
    if(v[index] != null && v[index].trim() == "Mytext")
    {
       v[index] = td2Value[index];
    }
    if(v[index] != null )
    {
      $(element).html(Math.round((td2Value[index] * 100 / v[index]) || 0) + '%');
    }

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> avalable</th>
                  <th> sold</th>
                  <th>  result </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>   
10<br/>Mytext<br/></td>
<td> 5<br/>2<br/></td>
<td>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
</td>        
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you. i editted my regex but it calculate wronge percentage. for example it returns  520% for the first row