# Wrong percentage of two number in the last td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that consists of `<tr>` and `<td>`'s and I show the percentage of the sold tickets in the third `<td>`.Also it suppost mytext as a number.My problem is the code calculates wrong percentage . i think this problem comes from html format such as space or 
 tag.
What should i do?
here is my snippet :

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(2)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);
  $('span.result', $this).each(function (index, element) {

    let v = $('td:nth-child(1)', $this).text().trim().split(/(\d+)/).filter(v => v);
    if(v[index] != null && v[index].trim() == "Mytext")
    {
       v[index] = td2Value[index];
    }
    if(v[index] != null )
    {
      $(element).html(Math.round((td2Value[index] * 100 / v[index]) || 0) + '%');
    }

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th> avalable</th>
                  <th> sold</th>
                  <th>  result </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>   
10<br/>Mytext<br/></td>
<td> 5<br/>2<br/></td>
<td>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
<span class="result"></span><br/>
</td>        
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you basically sold 52 out of 10, what is the percentage were you expecting?

Comment: @gurvinder372 the result would show percentage of 10 and 5 but it does not work . it must show 50% but it shows wrong number. because of space or maybe br tag in my html

Comment: if you want the percentage of 10 and 5, then change your markup accordingly. 5 and 2 should be in different cell of different row.

Comment: @gurvinder372 the calculation is correct. just press a enter after each <br/> tag in each td . you can see the correct percentage. the problem is with <br/> that makes the code wrong

Comment: deja vu?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765085/percentage-of-two-number-with-enter-key-works

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this one.

```
$(element).html(Math.round((parseInt(td2Value[index]) * 100 / parseInt(v[index])) || 0) + '%');
```

and if you want answer in decimal you should try parseFloat() instead of parseInt()

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your markup to keep `5` and `2` in different rows so that they are not picked up together as `52` while doing calculation.

Check this **demo** below.

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
  var $this = this,
    td2Value = $('td:nth-child(2)', $this).text().trim().split(/\D+/);
  $('span.result', $this).each(function(index, element) {

    let v = $('td:nth-child(1)', $this).text().trim().split(/(\d+)/).filter(v => v);
    if (v[index] != null && v[index].trim() == "Mytext") {
      v[index] = td2Value[index];
    }
    if (v[index] != null) {
      $(element).html(Math.round((td2Value[index] * 100 / v[index]) || 0) + '%');
    }

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> avalable</th>
      <th> sold</th>
      <th> result </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><span class="result"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><span class="result"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i cannot change the html format. because in some cases i need two value in each td

Comment: *because in some cases i need two value in each td* why?

Comment: i need it in my project. did you press an enter after each <br/> ?

Comment: No, but I still don't understand what does this have to do with enter and why *because in some cases i need two value in each td* ?

Comment: if i coud use that html format why i am asking the question here?i have problem so i asked the question to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You table tag's are wrong .Better change  table like this.And add the js code like below.

calculate the percentage with `cell one and two` then post the result with 3rd cell

```js
$('table tbody tr').each(function() {
 var res = Math.round(parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text())/parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text())*100)
 res = !isNaN(res) ? res :0
 $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text(res+'%')

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> avalable</th>
      <th> sold</th>
      <th> result </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 10</td>
      <td> 5</td>
      <td> </td>
      <tr>
        <td>Mytext</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i cannot change the html code.the calculation is correct. just press a enter after each <br/> tag in each td . you can see the correct percentage. the problem is with <br/> that makes the code wrong.not table tag because i need two value in each td

Comment: ya your problem is  correct .But its not fare to use like this in table.it take even more complicate in you dom function's.utilize the table tag properly

Comment: but i have to use like this. is there any way to solve this problem with <br/>?

Comment: without changing your html structure there is no other way .because closed only `</br>` not accessible in dom

Comment: but when i press Enter after each br it works correctly

Comment: ya ..its just a styling purpose of `break` the string.its not regular tag.if you call the td html its a 52 beacuse `</br>` just breaking the string.Better you could switch some other tag like `span` or properly use the table tag like above answer